# Cannot create Integration Services Catalog without Azure Subscription

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an existing SQL Server 2017 install. I added SSIS via a different installation media/setup. It instance now shows as having Integration Services installed. I have rebooted many times. I am using SSMS 18.4

I want to create a catalog, SSISDB, locally to the installed instance. The only option present is Create SSIS IR button. There is no separate OK/Cancel buttons.

How do I create the catalog locally?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window has cut off the buttons at the bottom.  SSMS has some high-DPI rendering issues.  Try a lower desktop resolution or [Tab]ing around that dialog.  EG

[image]

Comment: Ugh!  That was the problem.  Thank you David!